# HTTP 401 error while automating but working fine in case manual testing

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Suddenly I am facing this login issue in `FireFox`

```
HTTP Status 401 - Authentication Failed: Error validating SAML message
type Status report

message Authentication Failed: Error validating SAML message

description This request requires HTTP authentication.
```

While running the automated script (Selenium webdriver-Java).

In-case of manual testing, the application login successfully, but if I clear cookie, the above error message is displayed.

Could someone let me know what could be the reason?

`Note`: I am not facing any such issue in Chrome.

Comment: Please add the code of your test script that is causing the error and explain how you login when testing manually. Which browser do you use?

Comment: @Würgspaß Edited the question.Please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

WebDriver always start new firefox which does not have any cookies, addons etc.. i am expecting you can avoid this issue by calling your profile. please follow below steps

1. close the firefox browser
2. Run dialog box, type in: ‘firefox.exe -p' and then Click OK

if above step does not open profile window, then try below 3 step

3. provide complete location of firefox for example in my lap 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe -p'
4. create new profile and start it. (ex: profile name is myProfile)
5. login into web app and save any authenticated related ones if any

   ```
    ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();

   FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("myProfile");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
   ```

Thank You,
Murali